# Activity Monitor % Processor Time grayed out on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, activity-monitor

The *% Processor Time* graph at *Activity Monitor* for remote connections stopped working and it grayed out after the physical SQL Server restart (image below), but when I get in the server with the same Domain User it works fine. It was also working fine on remote connections before the restart and I have noticed that it takes significantly more time to load the Processes than before.

[image: % Processor Time grayed out]

The problem is happening to all users that try to see the Processor Time remotely including **sa** and server admins so I would think it´s not a permission issue. The server runs Windows Server 2012 and SQL Server 2012.

What could be happening? or How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance! and sorry about my English.

Comment: [There is a Connect item about this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/350723/ssms-activity-monitor-does-not-show-cpu-time-for-remote-instances) - are you going across domains?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I just tried what it says but it didn't work, I even restarted my pc after the changes made to see if it worked but it was useless in my case.

Comment: Ok. You know Activity Monitor is neither the best nor the only place to get CPU usage data, right?

Comment: Yes I know, but I´m the kind of person that can't stand having a problem without an answer, if this happened there is a cause and I do really want to find it, I will keep searching and if I get an answer I will post it here.

Comment: The simple solution is to run `cd \windows\system32` and then run `lodctr /R` in order to manually rebuild all performance counters (including the SQL Server performance counters) - this is a known issue (at lest this is one known issue with the same behavior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it is not a solution but we had a programmed restart and after that everything works fine, it is a production server so we couldn't restart before but that solved it.

Comment: For some reason someone downvoted your answer even so it worked for you and therefore can work for the next user (which is common in SO sites and make me hate these systems). I Upvoted the answer even so it is not the solution I would take. The simple solution is to run `cd \windows\system32` and then run `lodctr /R` in order to  manually rebuild all performance counters (including the SQL Server performance counters) - this is a known issue (at lest this is one known issue with the same behavior)